# Cohort analysis in a long time-series dataset: how do I retain people who move in and people who move out of the cohort?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I need help with a dataset that contains individuals between 0-17 years of age between the years 1997-2019. The dataset is in a long format, thus, there's multiple rows for each individual. I follow cohorts of people of a certain age at a certain time (e.g., newborns at year 1997, newborns at year 1998, 1-year olds at year 1997 etc), and look at the retantion-rate over time.
So for example, the newborn-cohort in 1997, how many of these people are still in the same town (and are alive) for each following year? So far all fine.

Now, I want to look at the individuals in each cohort that does not stay in the cohort. So for each year I want
a) a summary of people moving out/dying, and
b) a new df containing all these people for the whole time-serie (1997-2019), as well as
c) people moving out and later on also moving back in (which makes them join the cohort again).

I asked a similar question recently ([Retain observations that hasn't occured in the year before in a long time-series dataset in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70924466/retain-observations-that-hasnt-occured-in-the-year-before-in-a-long-time-series/70925114#70925114))
where I got an answer using `split()`, `setdiff()` and a `for()`-loop to succeed. It worked out well, but I can't figure out how to write the code to give me the results described above.

Edit: I added some example-code of what code I used to create my cohorts:

````
###The following codes gives me newborn cohorts per year and 
follows each cohort over time
#Flag newborns in the long dataset and keep only those individuals 
that #at one of the years has been 0 years old  
output_long_newborn %<>%
  arrange(ID, Year) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(
  flag_newborn2 = case_when(
    Age==0 ~ 1,
    TRUE ~ 0
  )) %>%
mutate(
  flag_newborn = case_when(
    sum(flag_newborn2) > 0 ~ 1,
    TRUE ~ 0
  )) %>%
filter(flag_newborn==1) %>%
ungroup()

#Create cohort-df for newborns
users_1997_2019_newborn <- output_long_newborn %>%
  arrange(Year, ID) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice_min(Year, n = 1) %>%
  dplyr::rename(cohort = Year)

 #Create final df
  cohort_1997_2019_newborn <- output_long_newborn %>%
  group_by(Year, ID) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  left_join (users_1997_2019_newborn, by = 'ID') %>%
  xtabs(~ cohort + Year, data = .)```
````

That's step one. Now, I want to go on with a, b and c above, that is to keep the individuals that for each cohort and for each year move out permanently and the ones that move out and move back into the cohort. I have tried using the code provided in the earlier question but without success.

Edit #2: So, running the code above could result in a dataset similar to the following:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(123)
df <- tibble(
  id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5,     # first year
         1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7,  # 4 moves out, 6,7 move in
         2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8  # 1,5 moves out, 4,8 move in
     ), 
  year = c(rep(2009, 5), 
       rep(2010, 6), 
       rep(2011, 6)), 
  age = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
      1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0,
      2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0) # extra column
    )
```

This is where the problem occurs, since I filter out only individuals that are 0 years old at one or another point in time. So when running code calculating differences between years, people that have no prior age will always be seen as new joiners. I think I somehow need to isolate each cohort and compare each year for each cohort. But I am not sure.

Comment: Seems you could use the same approach of prior [E.T. Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70924466/retain-observations-that-hasnt-occured-in-the-year-before-in-a-long-time-series/70925114#70925114) with your `df_list <- vector('list', 21)`  #22 -1,now being 21, not 2. Assumes you've been rigorous with ID numbers (no reuses except as to moving back in) and data as presented there match yours...what have you tried?

Comment: @Chris I added some example-code in my original message above. I'm starting to think I don't really understand what I'm doing. I've tried flagging all individuals that were 0 years old at one of the years (1997-2019), and filtering out only these individuals. After that I tried using the code written by E.T._Stack with the result that I keep all the newborns per year (since they do not exist the year before, they are considered "newcomers"). This is not what I want. Rather, I want the results of a, b and c written above, but I can't figure out how to get there.

Comment: With reference to @e-t-stack 's tibble in the prior?, what is your tibble now? That, coupled with your abc approach above would likely help clarify. Which is to say, put some working data here and you'll have a well formed question.

Comment: @Chris Thank you for your feedback! It makes me think about what my actual problem is.  I edited my original post some more, adding a tibble.

Comment: Okay, so perhaps a lookup table (LUT) where names are unique (IDs) and value(s) is year the ID was issued, that will certainly address the re-entrant members... perhaps just indexing ` joined <- df[which(df$age == 0), c('id', 'year')]
# A tibble: 8 × 2
     id  year
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1  2009
2     2  2009
3     3  2009
4     4  2009
5     5  2009
6     6  2010
7     7  2010
8     8  2011 > joined[1,]
# A tibble: 1 × 2
     id  year
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1  2009` Still head scratching, but this lets you test/add/subtract...

Comment: Replace your zeros with a constant, say `1/365
[1] 0.002739726`? This could be any number of days/365, depending on what underlying data you have and when in the year the cohort 'census' is taken, but as a practical matter, not using zero to express a newborn is likely useful if you are not restricted to integers.